# Algorithm 2e - removing semicolons on lines with comments

Tags: algorithm2e

I am using `\DontPrintSemicolon`in algorithm2e but the semicolons at the end of lines with comments are still there. This was a problem that was supposed to have been resolved in version 5.0, but I am at version 5.2 and still have this problem. Here is a MWE; would appreciate any leads:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lined,boxed]{algorithm2e}% using version 5.2
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwInOut{Declare}{Declare}
    \caption{COM\_MIN Algorithm}\label{alg:commin}
    \KwIn{ \texttt{R}: relation; $Pr$: set of simple predicates}
    \KwOut{$Pr'$: set of simple predicates}
    \Declare{$F$: set of minterm fragments} 
    \Begin{
        $Pr' \leftarrow \emptyset$; $F \leftarrow \emptyset$; \hfill \{initialize\} \\
        find $p_{i} \in Pr$ such that $p_{i}$ partitions \texttt{R} according to $Rule~1$ \;
        $Pr' \leftarrow  Pr' \cup p_{i}$ \;
        $Pr \leftarrow Pr - p_{i}$ \;
        $F \leftarrow F \cup f_{i}$ ; \hfill \{$f_{i}$ is the minterm fragment according to
        $p_{i}$\} \\
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\DontPrintSemicolon` only affects semicolons printed at the end of line denoted by `\;`. But you put the semicolons before comments explicitly, so they are not removed. Just remove `;` to get the desired result:

```
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwInOut{Declare}{Declare}
    \caption{COM\_MIN Algorithm}\label{alg:commin}
    \KwIn{ \texttt{R}: relation; $Pr$: set of simple predicates}
    \KwOut{$Pr'$: set of simple predicates}
    \Declare{$F$: set of minterm fragments} 
    \Begin{
        $Pr' \leftarrow \emptyset$; $F \leftarrow \emptyset$ \hfill \{initialize\} \\
        find $p_{i} \in Pr$ such that $p_{i}$ partitions \texttt{R} according to $Rule~1$ \;
        $Pr' \leftarrow  Pr' \cup p_{i}$ \;
        $Pr \leftarrow Pr - p_{i}$ \;
        $F \leftarrow F \cup f_{i}$ \hfill \{$f_{i}$ is the minterm fragment according to
        $p_{i}$\} \\
    }
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Comment: Aarghhh -- many times I do it to myself... Thank you; I totally missed these explicit semicolons...